# Corel Draw alternatives

Tags: vector-graphics, drawing, coreldraw

Corel Draw is a really good vector graphics application but its price is a 'bit' high. Could you recommend me some alternatives? I only know InkScape from out of the blue.. and it's a bit behind Corel Draw. :)

Commercial alternatives are also 100% fine.

Comment: Huh guys thank you. I should convert this to wiki or I don't know... vote up everyone accept someone randomly? All of them are great examples and worth the tick..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else posted [this site](http://alternativeto.net/) for alternatives in another superuser post but thought it would be useful for you.

Some of its suggestions are [Open Office - Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/)

EDIT: Removed Inkscape as alternative as poster has already tried, sorry should have read the full question!!

Comment: Sir, you got the accept for the alternative page. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/fireworks/) and [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/) would be two other alternatives.

Rant: i don't like either of them, but...

Answer (score 2):

InkScape is the only free alternative I know.

Some Commercial alternative products are :

[Xara Xtreme](http://www.xara.com/us/products/xtreme/) ($89)
[Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/) ($599)

Answer (score 2):

I would try to find an older, legitimate copy on ebay. This will give you the program that you really want, and you'll be eligible for discounted upgrades in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want layers:
- Pixlr Image Editor (cloud: pixlr.com/editor) -> the best I think (no programs installed and do not wait to load)
- Googe Docs Draw (cloud: docs.google.com)
- Gimp (free)
- Open Office Draw (free)
- PhotoFiltre Studio (cheap)

If you don't wanna layers:
- PhotoFiltre (free)

Added in 18th August 2010:
There is a greater list on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_editors

Comment: These are photo editors, not **vector** graphics editor.

Comment: Well, since CorelDraw (CD) and PhotoShop (PS) are classified as vector graphics editor, why can't that options be classified also? They support layers, as CD and PS...

Answer (score 2):

If you have have a Linux machine to hand (try dual booting perhaps?), you can try the open source release of the well-regarded [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/).